# Perl: Assign Coderef to Method without Symbol Table Hacks

Tags: perl, oop, class, object, methods

Building on from a previous query regarding Class::Struct vs Object::Accessor, I'd like to find the best way to assign package subs from coderefs in object constructors. Hey, I've got the OO attributes down, so lets get to the methods :)

Note that I said 'best' way. I've already found two ways of doing it which also seem to be popular answers in similar questions, but they require circumventing strict and warnings respectively.

Note that the example gives the class-user the ability to override the formatting method at construction. Poor example, but you get the idea. To preemptively rebut the OO-purists, this makes more sense in my particular design than making the class-user subclass it with their own overridden version.

Here are my two attempts:

```
use 5.014;
use autodie;
use strict;
use warnings;

package Account {
    use base 'Object::Accessor';

    sub new {
        my ($type, %args) = @_;

        my $self = bless { }, $type;
        $self->mk_accessors(qw(
            first_name last_name age_in_years activated
        ));

        $self->first_name(  $args{first_name  } // 'Default First Name'  );
        $self->last_name(   $args{last_name   } // 'Default Last Name'   );
        $self->age_in_years($args{age_in_years} // 'Default Age in Years');
        $self->activated(   $args{activated   } // 'Default Activated'   );

        {
            # Stop skim reading and look here!

            no warnings 'once';
            *formatted = $args{formatted} || sub {
                return 'Default formatting routine';
            };
        }

        return $self;
    }
}

my $account = Account->new;
say $account->formatted;

# Output: Default formatting routine
```

And the other one:

```
use 5.014;
use autodie;
use strict;
use warnings;

package Account {
    use base 'Object::Accessor';

    sub new {
        my ($type, %args) = @_;

        my $self = bless { }, $type;
        $self->mk_accessors(qw(
            first_name last_name age_in_years activated
        ));

        $self->first_name(  $args{first_name  } // 'Default First Name'  );
        $self->last_name(   $args{last_name   } // 'Default Last Name'   );
        $self->age_in_years($args{age_in_years} // 'Default Age in Years');
        $self->activated(   $args{activated   } // 'Default Activated'   );

        {
            # Stop skim reading and look here!

            no strict 'refs';
            *{'formatted'} = $args{formatted} || sub {
                return 'Default formatting routine';
            };
        }

        return $self;
    }
}

my $account = Account->new;
say $account->formatted;

# Output: Default formatting routine
```

The former approach **should** work without warnings, but it doesn't because Perl thinks I'm not using it anywhere and flags it up as a warning at runtime. The latter doesn't work without circumventing strict, and that's how it should be :)

All I'm doing is assigning a method to a user-supplied coderef. There should be an easy way of doing this.

Note that defining a new sub that calls the user defined coderef doesn't work either, since the lexical %args can't be accessed from it.

Whilst our assigns package variables, it can't do subs.

Refraining the escape from the garden of strict and warnings, what is the cleanest way to do this? Hell, there's probably a way to do this using the Object::Accessor module that I just don't know about.

Comment: The problem here isn't that it does "symbol table hacks"; the problem is that the code is *broken* unless there's only ever one Account object in existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be stored in $self:

```
$$self{formatted} = sub { ... };
```

Or put in a lexical:

```
my $formatted = sub { 1; }; # Dummy sub for initial assignment
sub new
{
    ...
    $formatted = sub { ... };
}

sub formatted { $formatted->(@_) }
```

Or just put up with the no strict 'refs'.  As long as it's in a small, well-contained block like you're doing above, I've never considered it evil. Or rather, it is evil, but a small, well-contained one.

Comment: Hmm, the first approach could work quite nicely. Am I right in saying that the first approach would reevaluate the anonymous sub per constructor call? If so, I suppose I could store the default coderef in a state variable, and then assign it per call, which should theoretically only assign the actual reference, not reevaluate the whole anonymous sub every time.

Comment: Actually, for former approach works, but none of the OO-method calling syntactic magic works with it, so I'm now going to try your second suggestion  :)

Comment: OK, after trying all of this approaches you suggested, I'm going to stick to the warnings-circumvention approach. Unfortunately, I'm disabling **all** warnings when I only want to disable the specific warning for defining unused symbols. The perldiag documentation is extremely dense; do you know what the specific warning type is for that particular violation? Thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you want 'formatted' to be a customizable per-object method, and not override the method for the whole package/class (i.e. all objects) on each constructor call (which assigning to the package sub would do), you can assign the subref to an object "private" key and call it from a normal method:

```
sub new { 
    my ($type, %args) = @_;
...
    $self->{_formatted} = $args{formatted} // sub { 'default' };
}

sub formatted {
    my ($self) = shift;
    return $self->{_formatted}->($self,@_);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`strict` is *made* to be able to turn it off for specific code where you want to do things that you don't want to do accidentally. Especially, if you do it like you're doing, at the smallest possible scope. It works the same way that pragmas do in C. It allows you to "break the rules" without becoming vulnerable to the myriad problems without the "rules".

However, if you do not want to turn off any of the "rules", then you should take a look at [`Symbol`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Symbol). Specifically `qualify_to_ref` will return a reference to a symbol, so that in casting it back into a symbol (see below) no alarms get triggered.

So for the code you present, you could do:

```
*{ Symbol::qualify_to_ref( 'formatted' ) } 
    =  $args{formatted} 
    || sub { return 'Default formatting routine'; }
    ;
```